# How to create toggle switch on-off buttons in Angular 4 with [(ngModel)] two way data binding

Tags: javascript, css, html, angular, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

Need to implement *switch* ON-OFF buttons similar to the image attached in question...

Comment: http://www.wisdomofjim.com/blog/angular-2-ui-switch-a-nice-reusable-component can get you started.

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/overview

Answer (score 6):

use [ngx-toggle-switch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toggle-switch) library

install `npm install ngx-toggle-switch --save`

Usage:-

```
import { UiSwitchModule } from 'ngx-toggle-switch';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, UiSwitchModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

in markup language:-

```
<ui-switch></ui-switch>
```

For Two way binding

```
<ui-switch [(ngModel)]="enable"></ui-switch>
```

For document of the Packge please refer :- [ngx-toggle-switch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toggle-switch)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I don't want to implement it with any third party plugin or library, that you have suggested. Is it possible to implement with CSS or bootstrap toggle switch with angular4 ??

Comment: Is there any reason not to use third party plugin or library...?

Comment: No specific reason, but want to try the implementation with open source bootstrap or normal css

Answer (score 5):

You can get the functionality with normal check box and some css.
Below is the code which will help.

Css :

```
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.switch input {display:none; background-color: #ccc;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
   background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 0px;
   right: 0px;
  bottom: -3px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(20px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(20px);
  transform: translateX(20px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Html :

```
<div class="row">
                <label>Yes</label>
                <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isNewProfile">
                <span class="slider round"></span>
                </label>
                <label>No</label>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But, is it possible to make it with Bootstrap switch on/off button, to make it to look beautiful? And the css styles will be similar to the image attached

Answer (score 0):

**This works on my site**

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-switch pt-4">
     <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="activeStatus" 
       name="activeStatus" [(ngModel)]="user.activeStatus">
     <label class="custom-control-label" for="activeStatus">Is Active</label>
</div>
```